# Returning SQL as decimal

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use Dashing as the project with Ruby.

I have a SQL query that returns `19.42` when run in the database. However, when I put it into code it returns `.1942`. What I am trying to figure out is how to get the decimal point to move right by two places.

Here is what the query and code look like:

```
require 'mysql2'

SCHEDULER.every '2h', :first_in => 0 do |job|

  # MySQL connection
  db = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "host", :username => "username", :password => "password", :port => port, :database => "database" )

  sql6 = "SELECT AVG(tickets.total_user_waiting) / (60 * 60) AS 'Total Tickets' FROM tickets WHERE tickets.status IN ('resolved', 'archived') AND tickets.date_resolved between date_format(date_sub(now(), interval 7 day), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') and date_format(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59');"
  response_sql = db.query(sql6)

send_event('response_sql',    {current: response_sql.first['Total Tickets']})
```

Here is the result of the SQL query alone from the database:

```
+-------------+
| 19.40648160 |
+-------------+
```

The output of the code that is written in Ruby looks like:

```
0.194064816E2
```

I'm not so much worried about removing the end numbers as I am just getting the decimal two places to the right, although that would be ideal.

I've tried select round but had no luck with that in the database.

Comment: `0.194064816E2` is the same number. It's simply expressed in scientific notation. `100 == 1E2 => true`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution that fixed the issue I was having is.

```
send_event('response_sql',    {current: response_sql.first['Total Tickets'].ceil})
```

So what I did was added `.ceil` to the end of the send event. It then rounded it to just two numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The value `0.194064816E2` is mathmatically equivelent to `19.40648160`. It's as if you wrote `0.194064816 x 10^2`. For instance, if I fire up IRB and throw that value into a variable, the proper float returns:

```
2.0.0-p481 :001 > x = 0.194064816E2
 => 19.4064816
```

I'm not sure why Ruby is printing that particular notation, but if you're performing any sort of additional operations, all of the numbers should work out properly.

Comment: My apologies. I corrected integer to float. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Thank you for that. The output is being put into a dashing widget named number. I'm assuming that is why it is being displayed incorrectly. I'll give that a shot.